# SwiftUI: Disable "swipeActions" on specific rows only

Tags: swiftui

I want to enable `swipeActions` for some rows of a `List` while other rows do not have this action.

Here is an example:

```
List {
    ForEach(1..<100) { i in
        Text("\(i)")
            .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                Button {
                    total += i
                } label: {
                    Label("Add \(i)", systemImage: "plus.circle")
                }
                .tint(.indigo)
            }
            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                Button {
                    total -= i
                } label: {
                    Label("Subtract \(i)", systemImage: "minus.circle")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

How would one disable the `swipeActions` for let say the 50 row?

Comment: Add a condition before the .swipeActions to check the index?

Comment: [selectionDisabled(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/selectiondisabled(_:)) could be what you are looking for.

Comment: Using `.selectionDisabled` does not have any effect on `.swipeActions`

Comment: just return no actions

Comment: malhal Thank you, you give me a better Idea to improve my answer, @VladimirAmiorkov check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 17.2 the use of `.disabled(i == 50)` no longer works. This might be an iOS bug in 17.2 as in 17.0 it works but for this reason I am updating this answer and will update if it gets resolved by Apple.

From iOS 17.2 the best way of making this work is with the approach described by Basel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77425850/3801632).

**Old answer:**

While it seams there are multiple ways to achieve this I ended you using an approach provided to me in the https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/740935?answerId=771248022#771248022 thread which simply uses the system `.disabled()` modifier on the `Button` inside the `.swipeActions()` and this approach looks like the "built-in" approach.

Here is the code:

```
List {
    ForEach(1..<100) { i in
        Text("\(i)")
            .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                Button {
                    total += i
                } label: {
                    Label("Add \(i)", systemImage: "plus.circle")
                }
                .tint(.indigo)
                .disabled(i == 50)
            }
            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                Button {
                    total -= i
                } label: {
                    Label("Subtract \(i)", systemImage: "minus.circle")
                }
                .disabled(i == 50)
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer:**

A better solution is using `if` modifier

add this extension to your project

```
extension View {
    /// Applies the given transform if the given condition evaluates to `true`.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - condition: The condition to evaluate.
    ///   - transform: The transform to apply to the source `View`.
    /// - Returns: Either the original `View` or the modified `View` if the condition is `true`.
    @ViewBuilder func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if condition {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

then use it like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var total = 0
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(1..<100) { i in
                Text("\(i)")
                    .if(i != 5) { view in
                        view
                            .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                                    Button {
                                        total += i
                                    } label: {
                                        Label("Add \(i)", systemImage: "plus.circle")
                                    }
                                    .tint(.indigo)
                                
                            }
                            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                                    Button {
                                        total -= i
                                    } label: {
                                        Label("Subtract \(i)", systemImage: "minus.circle")
                                    }
                                
                            }
                    }
                   
                   

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Old Answer:**

You can do it something like this, not a perfect solution but it does work

in my example I disable swiping if the item is 5

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var total = 0
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(1..<100) { i in
                Text("\(i)")
                    .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                        if i != 5 {
                            Button {
                                total += i
                            } label: {
                                Label("Add \(i)", systemImage: "plus.circle")
                            }
                            .tint(.indigo)
                        }
                    }
                    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                        if i != 5 {
                            Button {
                                total -= i
                            } label: {
                                Label("Subtract \(i)", systemImage: "minus.circle")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                   

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using the `if` modifier you can do the following in your swipeAction

```
.swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
    if someCondition {
        Button {
            sectionRowIndex = index
            showDeleteTransactionAlert = true
        } label: {
            Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.fill")
                .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
        }
        .tint(.red)
    } else {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```